# make variable global to multiple files in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I want to make a variable global to more than 2 files so that operating in any file reflects in the file containing the variable.

what I am doing is:

**b.py**

```
import a

x = 0
def func1():
    global x
    x = 1   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print x
    func1()
    print x
    a.func2()
    print x
```

**a.py**

```
import b

def func2():
    print b.x
    b.x = 2
```

I have searched for threads here and find `from a import *` is making copies and `import a` is otherwise. I expect the code above to print `0 1 1 2`(sure it should be in new lines) when execute `python b.py` but it's showing `0 1 0 1`

How does one implement that?

Comment: You are making a cyclic import here.. importing b in a.py and a in b.py, instead you can only import the required x from a in b.py

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I think globals like this (using the global keyword) are evil.
But one way to restructure it is to put your globals into a class in a SEPARATE module to avoid circular imports.

**a.py**

```
from c import MyGlobals

def func2():
    print MyGlobals.x
    MyGlobals.x = 2
```

**b.py**

```
import a
from c import MyGlobals

def func1():
    MyGlobals.x = 1   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print MyGlobals.x
    func1()
    print MyGlobals.x
    a.func2()
    print MyGlobals.x
```

**c.py**

```
class MyGlobals(object):
    x = 0
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ python b.py 
0
1
1
2
```

Comment: The module `c` itself could provide the globals, rather than wrapping them in a class.

Comment: why wrap with a class? without the class the problem is still there.

Comment: I only wrap it in a class because I feel its more appropriate in case you did want to pass it around or store it on another class as a configuration object, and not actually store a module object.