# Accessing global cursor from within function

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

This works okay (some code ommited for brevity):

```
# main.py
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('foo')
```

As does this:

```
# other.py
def do_something(script, cursor):
  cursor.execute(script)

# main.py
from other import do_something
cursor = db.cursor()
do_something('foo', cursor)
```

But (as I understand it) the "lower" scope of the function should be able to access the "higher" (global?) scoped cursor - why should I need to pass the cursor as an argument on my function? So I tried this:

```
# other.py
def do_something(script):
  cursor.execute(script)

# main.py
from other import do_something
cursor = db.cursor()
do_something('foo')
```

Which returns:

```
NameError: global name 'cursor' is not defined
```

I thought "maybe running a query against the cursor is a write operation, not a read" and tried:

```
# other.py
def do_something(script):
  global cursor
  cursor.execute(script)

# main.py
from other import do_something
cursor = db.cursor()
do_something('foo')
```

Same error. What am I missing?

EDIT: It sounds like "how do I make variable names global across different modules" is the wrong question. The right question - if I have a primary handler, a SQL cursor and a file of common functions, how should I structure my files / imports?

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
# other.py
def do_something(script):
  global cursor
  cursor.execute(script)

# main.py
from other import do_something
import other
  other.cursor = db.cursor()
  do_something(script)
```

My English is not good, so you can read these answers

- **[Global Variable from a different file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400525/global-variable-from-a-different-file-python)**
- [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files-in-python)
- [make variable global to multiple files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814316/make-variable-global-to-multiple-files-in-python)

Comment: Interesting! So it sounds like perhaps my current structure is the wrong way to go (see edit). I'll have a look through those answers and see if I can find a better approach.